# Network Error when connecting React frontend to

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, next.js

The app is using next.js connected to express, which is in turn connected to AWS MySql.

I'm trying to initially load some products I have stored on my database. However, i get the following network error:-

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I troubleshooted the frontend code by using an external api and that works fine, so it's something to do with the express middleware.

See code excerpts below...

index.js

```
import '../scss/style.scss';
import NavBar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

const Index = (props) => (
    <div>

    <NavBar />
    <h1>See our products below yeah</h1>
    </div>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
    const res = await fetch('localhost:3000/');
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        posts: data
    }
}

export default Index;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const db = require('../lib/db')
const escape = require('sql-template-strings')

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()


  server.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      let sql = 'SELECT * FROM products'
      db.query(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
          if (err) {
              throw err;
          } else {
              return res.json({
                  data: rows
              })
          }
      })
  })
...
```

db.js

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')

const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: "XXX",
    database: "XXX",
    user: "XXX",
    password: "XXX"
  }
})

exports.query = async query => {
  try {
    const results = await db.query(query)
    await db.end()
    return results
  } catch (error) {
    return { error }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you have api request from a different server you have to setup CORS on both frontend and backend

Link: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: I've added server.use(cors) below the server declaration and thus on the backend, but I still get the same error. I'm convinced I'm not declaring the 'fetch' correctly or declaring my route correctly in express. @Aravind